# How to convert type long to type String ? To solve : 'Encode(java.lang.string)' in android.net.Uri cannot be applied to long

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I am developing an android app in which the data is taken from JSON. And I am generating the listview through Baseadapter. When I click the number (`TextView`), I need to make a phone call to that number. I have tried it as follows

```
//initialization
public long abc;

in getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{ 

    abc = m.getNumber();


    number.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent out = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(abc)));
            context.startActivity(out);
        }
    });

  return convertView;
}
```

Error I am getting is `'Encode(java.lang.string)' in android.net.Uri cannot be applied to long.`

Actually what does it mean? How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your abc variable is long. convert it into String as error saying "Encode(java.lang.string)' in android.net.Uri cannot be applied to long"

```
 Intent out = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(String.valueOf(abc))));
           context.startActivity(out);
```

Comment: let me know if you still have any issue

Comment: I am getting an error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference"

Comment: your context value is null

Comment: have check you context value ?

Comment: Actually I fixed it myself and Thank you so much.

Comment: json feed was stored in cache which i pressed gave an error i guess. Now i removed cache so that it gets the json feed every time.

Comment: I think it is the reason. Do you think the same too.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for fixed this issue:

```
out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(Stirng.valueOf(abc))));
```

Or

```
out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(""+abc)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Covert value of abc variable to String. Or, use

```
out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +String.valueOf(abc)));
```

You may want to use ACTION_DIAL instead of ACTION_CALL. ACTION_DIAL gives user the opportunity to check number before calling, while ACTION_CALL will directly make a call to the given number.

Answer (score 0):

The variable abc is `long`. `Uri.encode()` requires a `String` parameter. So convert abc to a String to remove the error. 
The following are the options:

`Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(String.valueOf(abc)))`

or

`Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("" + abc))`